# reveal.js opacity of background image when printing to pdf

Tags: html, background, opacity, reveal.js, export-to-pdf

i am creating a presentation using reveal.js.
I do use some images as background in some slides.
I have reduced the opacity using css like

`html.dimbg .slide-background {
    opacity: 0.4 !important;}`

Then I call the image:
`<section  data-transition='zoom'  data-background="img.jpg" data-background-size="100%" data-state="dimbg">`

However, when I try to print as pdf (using the ?print-pdf option) the 
background images are at 100% opacity. Same happens when I use decktape to export to pdf.
In normal use from the browser the image shows correctly.

thx.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: I've opened an issue for it: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1973

Comment: No solutions yet..